# Getting Google Course Builder to deploy from Windows 7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have extremely limited programming experience, and I am trying to get Google Course Builder up and running to make a class on a website. I have tried a lot of things, and have probably screwed things up badly by this point, but hopefully the situation is salvageable with enough help.

So far I have:

1. Downloaded Course Builder to my Windows 7 64 bit pc
2. Manually installed python 2.7.17
3. Installed Cygwin manually
4. Ran `windows_start_local.bat` (Which installed Cygwin again)
5. This showed up in a new window:

> Compilation error building pycrypto-2.6.1. Please ensure a C compiler
>   is installed and functional on your system. On OS X, the most likely
>   cause of this problem is that you don't have the XCode Command Line
>   Tools installed. To fix this, run
>
> $ xcode-select --install
>
> and follow the instructions that appear, then re-run this command.
>   /usr/bin/bash: Exit 255.

6. Typed: `gcloud component install app-engine-python-extras` into CMD prompt and received a message that it was an invalid command
7. Typed: `easy_install http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/pycrypto-2.6.1/pycrypto-2.6.1.win32-py2.7.exe` into CMD prompt and it said pycrypto was installed and that dependencies had been processed.
8. Typed: `windows_start_local.bat` into CMD prompt again
9. Got the same error:

> Compilation error building pycrypto-2.6.1. Please ensure a C compiler
>   is installed and functional on your system. On OS X, the most likely
>   cause of this problem is that you don't have the XCode Command Line
>   Tools installed. To fix this, run
>
> $ xcode-select --install
>
> and follow the instructions that appear, then re-run this command.
>   /usr/bin/bash: Exit 255.

10. Typed: `easy_install http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/pycrypto-2.6.1/pycrypto-2.6.1.win32-py2.7.exe` into CMD prompt again.
11. Typed: `windows_start_local.bat` into CMD prompt again
12. Got that same error again.
13. Installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266
14. Came here because I have no idea what the heck I am doing.